# Angular form submission with dynamically added data bindings

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form:

```
<form ng-controller="NtCtrl" ng-submit="submitExercise()">

  <!-- Question input -->
  <input ng-model="exercise.question"/>

  <!-- Dynamically add answer options here -->
  <div id="options"></div>

  <!-- Click this button to add new field -->
  <button type="button" onclick="newAnswer()">Add answer</button>

  <!-- Click this button to submit form -->
  <button type="submit">Submit question</button>
</form>
```

with some JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var count = 1;

  function newAnswer() {
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    var attr = document.createAttribute('ng-model');
    attr.value = "exercise.answers." + qid; 
    input.setAttributeNode(attr);

    document.getElementById('options').appendChild(input);

    count ++;
  }

</script>
```

and an Angular controller:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('NtCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.exercise = {};
    $scope.submitExercise = function() {
        console.log($scope.exercise);
    });
});
```

I want to dynamically add answer options to a question by pressing the button. The problem is that when I submit the form, the answers are not present in `$scope.exercise`. I suspect this is because these fields are added after the original html is rendered.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't really the Angular way of doing things. You want to modify a data structure that is binded to the view. Create an array of answers, and simply push to that array when you want another row to show up:

```
<div id="options">
    <p ng-repeat="answer in answers">
        <input type="text" ng-model="answer.text" />
    </p>
</div>

<button type="button" ng-click="newAnswer()">Add answer</button>
```

And the new controller logic:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('NtCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.answers = [];

    $scope.newAnswer = function() {
        $scope.answers.push({text:"Sample"});
    }

    $scope.submitExercise = function() {
        console.log($scope.answers);
    });
});
```